# SSIS - Derived column Transformation Editor malfunction

Tags: sql, ssis, expression

There is a package that worked fine. I deleted it, and want to recreate the package.
When I ran this part of the Derived Column, it shows as RED color.
In the original package, it showeds BLACK i.e. no errors.

```
(DT_BOOT)(ISNULL(Request)? 0 : (LOWER(Request)== "yes" ? 1 : 0)

The Derived Column Name = Derived Column
The Derived Column = <Add as new column>
The Expression = As shown above
Data Type = Does not allow any input
```

Is there something else missing?

Comment: Maybe it's an error in your question but the expression is missing a closing bracket `)`

Comment: (DT_BOOT)(ISNULL(Request)? 0 : (LOWER(Request)== "yes" ? 1 : 0))   Yes I missed that one extra bracket - but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you duplicate the package? If you copied and pasted the derived column it's possible erros be thrown. It would be better if you add the Derived column component and configure it. Also save the project and check if the red indicator is gone.

Comment: I have deleted the OLD Package. Now I am recreating it from the ground up using a NEW Derived Column Transformation Tool. The error is till there

Comment: please post source metada

Answer (score -4):

THANK YOU Everyone! I have found the answer. Apparently, SSIS wants quotation marks for the COLUMN Name. Once I had **"Request"** inside quotaion marks, everything worked fine - no errors; no red.

(DT_BOOT)(ISNULL("Request")? 0 : (LOWER("Request")== "yes" ? 1 : 0)

Comment: no, that makes it a STRING value, not a column name.

Comment: A screenshot of the derived column dialogue with the variables expanded might help here. As it is it looks like you'll always have "0" returned.